# Read and update database with REST api MobilePush

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush, accountcontactrelation

I am using Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

I would like to use REST api to read data in MobilePush's database, and update the record in database. I read a document in:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createPushMessage.htm

I couldn't see a function that can read or update database. I only saw how to create a message and send the message.

Please, guide me to see where the function to read and update is.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "Update" endpoint documented ~5 items below your currently selected page.

[image]

Comment: Actually, what I meant by data was contact. I would like to read where a contact is and update the contact. I just found that the REST api I wanted should be in Contact category instead of Push category.